# RPC 'create_address' after restart daemon creates same addresses again

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

When I restart the daemon the method 'create_address' somehow cycles already used addresses (not used as in received monero but already created before).

is there a way to prevent the daemon from returning the same address twice?

Answer (score 2):

Subaddresses are deterministic, so the same index will yield the same address. If the wallet daemon is returning repeat addresses, it means it does not remember it has already gone through them. Most likely, you did not save before stopping the wallet daemon. Call the `store` RPC before quitting, or after generating a new subaddress (saving can get slow for large wallets, so you may want to save on a timer instead in that case, details will depend on your particular conditions).

Comment: great,  thank you for that quick response. i'll try that solution